# Scroll on page load only when page is reached from specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following to scroll to a section of my page on page load.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.smooth').offset().top
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible to only do this function if a specific button is clicked?

It is a blog page and the template has an anchor in it:

```
<a name="topicanchor"class="smooth top"></a>
```

The template also includes a menu of topics. I only want the page to scroll if it is a result of one of the topics from the menu being clicked.

ie. if a '`.topic-menu li a`' is clicked, load the page using the `scrollTop` function.

Thanks!

Comment: You could pass the link anchor as fragment `#anchor` in the url, then perform your animate function on the page load.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Thanks for the comments!

```
if (window.location.hash == "#topicanchor") {
$(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.smooth').offset().top
}, 2000);
return false;
});
} else {
}
```

I am also using this to attach the anchor in the template to the url:

```
$(function () {
$('.topic-menu li a').attr('href', function (_, oldHref) {
    return oldHref + "#topicanchor";
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried this way?

```
$(function(){
    $(".topic-menu li a").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.smooth').offset().top
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    });  
});
```

Comment: Suggestions on attempts to tackle the problem should be posted via comments. Answers are... answers. They should solve the problem.

Comment: Side note: _Have you tried_ and not _Did you tried_.

Comment: @marcio Gonzalez this makes the current page animate and the link does not take you to the page it is supposed to. I need the page that the link opens to animate.